# Ionic 3 HTTP Status Code 401 changed to 0

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 with spring boot at the back end. Spring Boot API are secured with Spring Security JWT Token.

While tying to execute any API, if the token has not expired the API is working properly.

Once token is expired its expected that API should return 401 status code, but in the ionic its always returning status code a 0(Zero).

However if we check the Network in the chrome browser, its showing correct response code as 401, but the ionic code its coming as 0(Zero)

Ionic Code Sample

```
var url = this.masterConfig.ADMIN_SERVER_URL +'/home';

  this.http.get(url,getOptions).subscribe(data => {
    console.log('Data :::'+data);
  },error =>{
    console.log('Error :::'+error);
    console.log('Error :::'+error.status);
    console.log('Error :::'+error.error);
  });
```

Network Logs
[image]

Console Log
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using the [Auth0 Angular2-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt) component, then this behavior [has been reported as an issue](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/issues/408).  That's the only time I've personally run into this behavior with Ionic 3 and HTTP response issues.